# Where to place a file controller within a spring application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-batch

So I have done research of the different layers of a spring application and so far for my first spring application I think I have done quite a good job. I am confused of where to put a FileController class. It might not even be a controller at all but more a service, i'm not sure. Maybe this is just a bad idea and I should just really use something like Spring batch. I just don't think I have the need for that type of scalability. I think the most complicated thing I might do is read and write an excel file of 5,000 lines max. The file controller below I would extend to read and write both text and .xls files. Should this be a controller and stay in the controller directory of a spring mvc web application or should this be a service and within the service directory or should this be a bean and some other directory? The file controller will only ever be accessed by a service object which will be called by a Spring MVC controller through a post or get request. I think my inexperience is really shining here.

Basically which annotation should I use: @Controller, @Bean, @Service?

I read that the @Controller annotation is primarily only used for request mappings. But it would make sense to have controllers that weren't web based.

Should I just use Spring Batch?

class example

```
public class FileController {

     List<String> readFile(String filename) { //some impl }
     String readFile(String filename) { //some impl }    

     void writeFile(List<String> content) { //some impl }
     void writeFile(String content) { //some impl }

     void close() { //some imple }  

}
```

I also thought about just adding the reading and writing to a file within the method that it is used but I thought this was a bad approach since I have the possibility of needed the same logic in the future, DRY.

Comment: Why not use @Component?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@Controller` annotation is used for beans that map methods onto URI and HTTP mehtod. Such beans sits on top of web layer typically.

As your bean is not going to be accessed from web, is can't be `@Controller`. From my opinion it is a service. So just rename it to `FileService` and annotate it with `@Service`.